# How to identify scripts being modified under two different SVN branches

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

**Here is some background to the way we work**

The team I work uses SVN to check in code. A branch is created for each Release people are working on. Trunk is the production code and no one touches it. A Release branch is merged into the trunk as soon as the Release goes live.

At any point of time, code from multiple Release branch is being deployed in 1 single Test environment as we dont have enough test environments. There have been instances where a script is being changed under two different branches by two different APs. And when we deploy the two branch into 1 Test environment, the code gets overwritten.

**Question**

What is the best way to identify all the scripts that are being changed in multiple branches at one point of time?